# WiX How to make an EventSource install but make the uninstall part optional

Tags: wix, conditional-statements, uninstallation, event-log

Does anyone know how to create an EventSource with WiX so that it gets installed but when the uninstall happens it becomes optional?
So let say when you uninstall, it presents you with a dialog asking you to choose whether it should remain on the computer or be removed.

I know that you can create your own .NET custom action and update the InstallExecuteSequence section with that logic but I would like to find out if you can do it "natively" with the util:EventSource component. As far as I know, it installs and uninstalls when you specify the component (containing the EventSource) in a specific feature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, EventSource doesn't support optional uninstall. When you uninstall a product, MSI removes all the resources it knows about, including the registry values EventSource creates. Uninstall would also remove the files the event source uses, so I'm not sure what the value is in making it optional...?

Comment: I thought that would be the case. The thing is we continually uninstall the previous version of an application and install the new version. We don't have the upgrade stuff in place so its out of the question. We just want to provide the option of keeping the event logs on uninstallation.